# How can I control caching for static assets when using Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm using the latest Sinatra and I'm hosting on Heroku. Is there a way I can set the caching headers for my static assets served from the `/public` directory?

Sinatra serves files from the `/public` directory before checking any routes that have been defined, so I can’t just the `cache_control` method inside a route.

The `/public` directory contains the CSS and JavaScript of my app. I don’t want the browser to download those files every single time, since they won't change often.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly why you want to do this? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Ehm. I'm serving CSS and JavaScript that doesn't change a lot, so I don't want the browser to load the file every single time, but to cache it until I upload a new version.

Comment: Can you define "it didn't work" better?

Comment: When I inspected the headers, they said *max_age: 0*.

Comment: So this question was closed because it cannot be "reasonably answered" after it was successfully answered. o.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`static_cache_control` setting](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Available%20Settings) to set the `Cache-Control` header for static files served by Sinatra:

```
set :static_cache_control, [:public, max_age: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365]
```

Note you need to use an explicit array `[...]`.

Also this will apply to all files in the `public` directory, i.e. you can’t specify different headers for css and javascript files.

(If you’re *not* using Heroku and are using Apache or Nginx to serve static files then this won’t work, in that case you’d need to configure your webserver separately).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. :) It also works locally, because I'm using rack there, too, I guess. Just a last question: When I change a file, will the new file be loaded automatically, or do I need to trigger that by appending some url parameter (like `?#{File.mtime(filename)})`?

Comment: @dotweb no, the new file won’t be loaded automatically (that’s pretty much the point of caching, the browser won’t even ask for it so it has no way of knowing it’s out of date). You’ll need to use some sort of url param or version name for your files.

Comment: Yeah, I just wasn't sure if the server already has some way to tell the browser to re-new the cache when it detects a new version. Anyways, I'll just use url params, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple Sinatra site using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'

get '/public/*' do
  cache_control :public, max_age: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
  'this is public'
end

get '/' do
    'hello world!'
end
```

When I requested '`/`', I got these headers:

```
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.5.0 codename Knife

200 OK
```

When I requested '`/public/foo`', I got these:

```
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 14
Server: thin 1.5.0 codename Knife

200 OK
```

It's working on a current Sinatra (1.3.3) on Ruby 1.9.3p194.

Comment: Oh, maybe I didn't explain it detailed enough. In the /public folder in my app (not the /public url), are all the files that can be viewed directly (a file /public/app.js can be accessed at /app.js without adding a route to the Ruby code.) I want those files to be cached. Now I see that what I tried didn't do what I actually wanted.